# facing issues while db2 version uplift

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, db2, version

Is there any way to suppress warnings in DB2 9.7 at system/session level. I have a requirement to suppress a particular warning and I dont want to do that for each individual stored procedure.

So if the database/DB2 experts on stackoverflow are aware of any such method, please share.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show a couple column definitions from 9.1 and their new definitions from the 9.7 tables?

Comment: sorry.. we are just copying the data in new db. And not changing any definition. Data/tables/stored procedures are all exactly the same without any difference except one that in old db "there length errors are handled themselves" and "new db is throwing run time errors"

Comment: The question was unclear. It could be interpreted as saying that the size doubled for some (or many) columns when the database was migrated. There might be some reasons for a similar kind of thing happening, so I wanted to be sure the encodings remained the same. Specific, actual definitions might have shown a possibility, as unlikely as it might be. No actual error code was given, and also example code seems to be hypothetical rather than actual. It was necessary to be sure.

Comment: Sorry, for the inconvenience caused. But we are not allowed to put the actual code here. N i ll update the qsn

Comment: There should only be a warning (SQLSTATE 01004) in DB2 9.7 when lengths differ and truncation occurs. See "Retrieval assignment" section in the [DB2 9.7 **Assignments and comparisons**](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008479.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-2-3-3&lang=en) topic. Without code that demonstrates the 'error' that we can run ourselves, it's not clear what "answer" can be provided.

Comment: in old db truncation was not happening.. this truncation will effect our functionality

Comment: That doesn't make useful sense. Examples of actual data type definitions of variables and columns in 9.1 and in 9.7 are needed to go farther. Definitions should all include any encoding attributes.

Comment: Provide a concrete example of code, that generates a warning in 9.7 but not in 9.1. Do this, instead of create a new identical question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how the max length of a column can increase by migrating to a newer version of the DBMS, but I assume there is another reason for that. If there is a specific table where you are facing problems with you can find out which routines that are dependent of that table with:

```
select x.routineschema, x.routinename 
from syscat.routines x 
join syscat.routinedep y 
    on x.specificname = y.specificname 
where btype = 'T' 
  and bschema = ? 
  and bname = ?
```

This is only an example, but you should be able to modify it to fit your needs.

Comment: Do you mean that 9.1 ignored the error and that 9.7 throws an exception instead?

Comment: 9.1 ignored the error and 9.7 throws the exception instead.. and this issue we are facing for many tables. And I agree that this is logically wrong. we are not supposed to insert max length data into smaller length variables. But this was working before in 9.1 and now its not working. And now to resolve this we need to do lots of work. So we are planning of avoiding this error and let it happen just like in 9.1. Or looking for some easy solution to fix/find all these at once

Comment: the max length of column is not increased. Its still the same but is was not throwing any errors in old db though its an error but now its hard for us to find and resolve these.

Comment: Weird, DB2 have always been very strict in these matters but I don't have anything to test on. Can you identify which tables that are likely to cause the error, for example tables with varchar columns of length 40?

Comment: NO.. this will not resolve our problem.. we found this issue till now with at least 7-8 tables but for sure we need to resolve this from everywhere we can face. SO need to look for easy way. Is there any tool which can help us in checking the column size and variable size is same or not

Comment: do u got any idea now to suggest for resolving this issue

Comment: I find it very unlikely that you will find a free and ready to go tool that can parse your code and come up with an answer. You probably will have to create your own. A fully fledged parser will be monstrous to write, but if there's a specific pattern in your code that you can use it should be doable. Once you parsed the sizes of the variables and what column that is at stake it should be easy to look up the size for the column in the catalogue.